# AppCenter Xamarin.ios configurations with APNS not sending notifications: stuck on Sending

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, apple-push-notifications, visual-studio-app-center

I have configured the Appceter Xamarin.ios  for sending notifications to iOS devices. I entered everything as is mentioned in AppCenter but when I send notifications, it says Sending and looks like its stuck there. I don't know what the issue can be. Any ideas here?

Comment: Are you testing in a real device and not the emulator?

Comment: Is the configuration of the apple set correctly?(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/sdk/push/xamarin-ios) (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/user-notifications/deprecated/remote-notifications-in-ios#creating-and-using-certificates)

Comment: Yes, I created an App ID with Push Notification Service enabled and then I created a  key .

Comment: I am testing on emulator, but the problem is notification is never sent

Comment: A message also comes when I install my app for first time asking whether I would like to receive notifications, I do Allow but no notification is sent or received

Comment: Its stuck on Sending

Comment: you cannot test push notifications on ios emulators, it will never work. App center does not have registered devices so it will never send anything, moreover your emulator cant register for/receive push notifications

Comment: But that doesn't happen with android. I did the same even though there is no device on which app is installed or no emulator running still notification was sent. I am lil confused here

Comment: @GiampaoloGabba is right. The difference is because Android is an "emulator" but iOS is just a simulator. They are very different, unlike iOS simulators, Android emulators receive push notifications and act as independent devices. You can even create an emulator with the Play Store and install apps from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/xamarin-notification-hubs-ios-push-notification-apns-get-started), push notifications cannot be tested on a simulator for iOS. You will need to test it on a device

> Because of configuration requirements for iOS push notifications, you
>   must deploy and test the sample application on a physical iOS device
>   (iPhone or iPad) instead of in the simulator.

Comment: This is not what I want, I am using AppCenter.